# Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. after updating my react-native version to 71.7

Tags: react-native

Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. This is a required option and must be explicitly set to `true` or `false` [click here to see the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhdxN.png)

I tried adding

1. useNativeDriver: false or true  //make it as false
2. tried ignoring the waring msg
   LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified.']);

none of the above solving my problem. and below is my package.json

```json
{
    "name": "xyz",
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "lint": "eslint .",
        "postinstall": "patch-package"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "2.2.2",
        "@notifee/react-native": "7.7.1",
        "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.6.1",
        "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.1.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "18.0.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/auth": "18.0.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "18.0.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "18.0.0",
        "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "8.0.0",
        "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.5.7",
        "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.1",
        "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.6",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.12",
        "axios": "0.19.0",
        "calendar-link": "2.4.0",
        "cross-env": "7.0.2",
        "dateformat": "3.0.3",
        "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "4.1.0",
        "intl": "1.2.5",
        "lodash": "4.17.21",
        "moment-timezone": "0.5.28",
        "patch-package": "7.0.0",
        "paths-js": "0.4.10",
        "prop-types": "15.7.2",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-core": "0.0.0",
        "react-native": "0.71.7",
        "react-native-animatable": "1.3.2",
        "react-native-asset": "2.1.1",
        "react-native-autocomplete-input": "4.2.0",
        "react-native-autoheight-webview": "1.6.1",
        "react-native-calendar-events": "2.2.0",
        "react-native-calendars": "1.212.0",
        "react-native-camera": "3.15.1",
        "react-native-chart-kit": "4.3.0",
        "react-native-credit-card": "0.1.9",
        "react-native-credit-card-input": "0.4.1",
        "react-native-device-info": "10.6.0",
        "react-native-dialog": "9.3.0",
        "react-native-document-picker": "3.2.4",
        "react-native-drawer-layout": "3.2.0",
        "react-native-dropdown-picker": "5.4.6",
        "react-native-elements": "1.2.6",
        "react-native-fast-image": "7.0.2",
        "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^12.1.0",
        "react-native-geocoding": "0.4.0",
        "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.12.0",
        "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "1.4.1",
        "react-native-htmlview": "0.16.0",
        "react-native-image-picker": "1.1.0",
        "react-native-image-viewing": "0.2.0",
        "react-native-input-credit-card": "0.5.5",
        "react-native-input-spinner": "1.7.10",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.1",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.5.6",
        "react-native-log-ios": "1.0.1",
        "react-native-maps": "^1.7.1",
        "react-native-masked-text": "1.13.0",
        "react-native-mime-types": "2.3.0",
        "react-native-modal": "13.0.1",
        "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "15.0.1",
        "react-native-network-info": "5.2.1",
        "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
        "react-native-paper": "3.2.1",
        "react-native-pathjs-charts": "0.0.34",
        "react-native-pell-rich-editor": "1.8.8",
        "react-native-permissions": "3.6.1",
        "react-native-phone-number-input": "2.1.0",
        "react-native-picker-select": "6.3.3",
        "react-native-pulse": "1.0.7",
        "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "1.3.1",
        "react-native-qrcode-svg": "6.0.3",
        "react-native-radio-button": "2.0.1",
        "react-native-ratings": "6.5.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "2.2.4",
        "react-native-responsive-screen": "1.4.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.3",
        "react-native-screens": "3.21.1",
        "react-native-searchable-dropdown": "1.1.1",
        "react-native-section-alphabet-list": "2.0.7",
        "react-native-sectioned-multi-select": "0.7.6",
        "react-native-shapes": "0.1.0",
        "react-native-simple-radio-button": "2.7.4",
        "react-native-snackbar": "2.4.0",
        "react-native-snap-carousel": "3.8.4",
        "react-native-splash-screen": "3.2.0",
        "react-native-star-rating": "1.1.0",
        "react-native-status-bar-height": "2.4.0",
        "react-native-step-indicator": "1.0.3",
        "react-native-store-rating": "1.0.1",
        "react-native-super-grid": "4.1.1",
        "react-native-svg": "11.0.1",
        "react-native-svg-charts": "5.3.0",
        "react-native-swipe-list-view": "2.1.3",
        "react-native-swipeout": "2.3.6",
        "react-native-swiper": "1.5.14",
        "react-native-tab-view": "3.5.2",
        "react-native-three-dots-loader": "1.0.1",
        "react-native-url-polyfill": "1.3.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "6.6.0",
        "react-native-webview": "^13.4.0",
        "react-navigation": "4.4.4",
        "react-redux": "7.1.1",
        "redux": "4.0.4",
        "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
        "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
        "rn-fetch-blob": "0.12.0",
        "rn-range-slider": "2.2.2",
        "swipeout": "1.0.0",
        "tipsi-stripe": "9.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
        "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
        "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
        "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "6.9.4",
        "eslint": "^8.19.0",
        "jest": "^29.2.1",
        "jetifier": "1.6.3",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.9",
        "prettier": "^2.4.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
        "typescript": "4.8.4"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    },
    "rnpm": {
        "assets": [
            "./app/assets/fonts/"
        ]
    }
}
```

Blow is my code snippet, and used 'Animated' in multiple files in my project. and added  'useNativeDriver'- true /false

```js
this.rotateValueHolder.setValue(0);
Animated.timing(
  this.rotateValueHolder,
  {
    toValue: 1,
    delay: 0,
    duration: 500,
    easing: Easing.ease,
    useNativeDriver: Platform.OS == "android" ? true : false,
    //}).start(() => this.startImageRotateFunction());
  },
  { useNativeDriver: Platform.OS == "android" ? true : false }
).start();
```

```js
Animated.loop(
  Animated.timing(0, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 3000,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  })
).start();
```

Comment: Post the code that the stack trace points to please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Guys, thanks for quick response and i have added some more details related to the issue , please review.